# ERROR 4620 --- [ restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am unable to clear this error.please help me .

my pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Fitness1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Fitness1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        
    </properties>
    

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
          </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Is the anything wrong in my pom file

Error showing as

> 2020-09-05 11:16:21.116 ERROR 10684 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The location [C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.6838231680585031970.8085] specified for the base directory is not a directory
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
> at com.example.fitness.Fitness1Application.main(Fitness1Application.java:11) [classes/:na]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
> at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The location [C:\Users\Priyanka\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.6838231680585031970.8085] specified for the base directory is not a directory
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.initBaseDir(Tomcat.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.getServer(Tomcat.java:657) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.getService(Tomcat.java:589) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:178) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:158) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
> ... 14 common frames omitted

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question here: [Tomcat Server creating Directories in tmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27865189/tomcat-server-creating-directories-in-tmp)

Seems that you are running on port 8085 and tomcat is trying to use the default folder.

My suggestion would be to declare a new folder for temporary files, and provide access for the tomcat user to write there.

I believe it's a matter of permissions to create a folder there in your pc, and nothing to do with your pom file.